# Is it possible to make a Room SQLite column NOT NULL while the entity field is nullable in a Kotlin class?

Tags: kotlin, android-room

It appears that Room infers column nullability from the nullability of the entity field type.

I want to initialize some of the fields in my entity with `null` but I don't want the underlying column to be nullable.

Is there a way to accomplish what I am trying to do in any other way?

Comment: What do you want to do if user pass object with null value for associated field? The exception from database is satisfying?

Comment: @MahdiRajabi  I'm trying to bind it with a form. I want to have an empty object for empty forms. Right now I'm creating another proxy class for the binding anyway...

Comment: "Right now I'm creating another proxy class for the binding anyway" -- and that sounds like the right answer. The entity needs to model the table structure, and if the table does not allow `null`, then neither should the entity. If you need that value to be `null` elsewhere, then that should be a different class than the entity class.

Comment: I think it's not clean solution, but you can use @Ignore annotation and define some extra nullable properties with custom accessor function like

Comment: class SampleUserClass{
    var name: String = ""
    @Ignore var mapName: String? = null
        set(value) {
            value?.run { name = value }
            field = value
        }
        get() {
            return name
        }
}

Comment: Wish it works, not sure